# Run Scrapy from script: Module not found error - projectname.items is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I try to run multiple crawlers like it's told in the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process). The script is running by calling `scrapy crawl crawler`.

Now by calling it via `python crawler.py` I get the following Error:

> from crawler.items import LinkItem
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crawler.items'; 'crawler' is not a package

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from crawler.items import LinkItem
from crawler.settings import DB_CREDS
```

Does anyone know how to handle this?

My project is named crawler. Could this be a problem?

Hierarchy:

```
Crawler
|-crawler
|  |-__pycache__
|  | |-...
|  |-spiders
|  | |-__pycache__
|  | |-__init__.py
|  | |-crawler.py
|  |-__init__.py
|  |-items.py
|  |-middlewares.py
|  |-pipelines.py
|  |-settings.py
|-scrapy.cfg
```

Comment: in your spiders folder, type pwd, and type ls where you put items and let me know the result

Comment: @parik I'm sorry but I don't get it. What do you want me to do?

Comment: i want to know the hierarchy of your project, you should have your items.py file in crawler folder

Comment: Ok I updated the Question

Comment: Run this command from the main `Crawler` directory and correct the path of python file path and see if that helps

Comment: yes I already tried to call the spider from the main `Crawler` directory but the problem was the same. Thats what made me surprised, because wirth `scrapy crawl crawler` ist no problem

Comment: Did you try to rename spider?

Comment: It was my first idea that maybe the name `crawler` make problems. So I renamed it to `basiccrawler`, but the problem was still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a kind of Python path problem. You run your script by `python` interpreter instead of `Scrapy`, thus you have to make sure that `Python` know where is your package. If you run as `Scrapy` command, then scrapy will take care it by the `scrapy.cfg`.

The easiest way to solve it is to append your project path to `PYTHONPATH`. For example `export PYTHONPATH=YOUR_PROJECT_PATH:$PYTHONPATH`. You may need to add this to your `.bashrc` file.

There are also other solutions, e.g., follow the distribution of package to install your project into site-packages python library.

Thanks.